# How to catch exceptions within simpy processes in Python?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, simulation, simpy

I am using the simpy package in Python for a simulation. I have a function called go() that includes a try-except block. Within the try block, there is a call to another function function_call(), which contains a simpy process. I want to raise an exception within the simpy process and catch it in the except block of the go() function. However, the exception raised within the simpy process is not being caught by the try-except block.

```py
env = simpy.Environment()

def go():
    try:
        function_call()
    except Exception:
        # Exception handling code

def function_call():
    env.process(self.diff_process())

def diff_process():
    yield env.timeout(1)
    raise Exception

def helper():
    go()
    yield env.timeout(2)

def main():
    env.process(helper())
    env.run()
```

The problem is that the exception raised within the diff_process() simpy process is not being caught by the try-except block in the go() function. How can I work around this issue? I am aware that I have a custom Exception class for my project, and I would like to utilize it if possible. I have also considered using event interrupts, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any suggestions or alternative approaches to catch exceptions raised within simpy processes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: env.process(self.diff_process()) creates a event and returns.  It does not wait for diff_process to finish.  So go() and function_call() have terminated before the timeout fires.  You can think of env.process as starting another thread.  

better tactics is to use events callbacks, to global events to signal bad events.  The other thing to try is to put yields in front of you calls.  Check out the docs for inter process communication.

Comment: pls add the minimal code which we can use to recreate the issue. for example how you set up the `env` and how you are calling `go` method etc.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still getting used to understanding processes but that helped a lot. I will move the exception logic into function_call() before the new process is created. (I also updated the question with more code to recreate the issue I initially had)

Answer (score 0):

In short

if a function has a yield in it you need to call it with env.process()

If you want to wait for env_process() to complete then use a yield env.process().  Otherwise you code will create the process and move on/exit.  its like env.process() creates a thread, and yield env.process() creates a thread, and waits for the new thread to finish

If you want to catch a exception, then you need all the calls to be a yield env.process()

I fixed the error with undefined self object and added yields env.process() as need to get the call stack right.

catching exceptions in simpy has many of the same issues as catching exceptions in a multi threaded application, so this pattern is not recommended.  For example, what if you want to start two processes so they run in parallel?  You cannot use yield env.process() because it will block until the first process is finish befor starting the second process, and if you use just env.process() you will not be able to catch the errors because the process creating the two processes with create both processes and exit.

A alternative is to use a event to monitor progress and the event gets triggered when a exception happens by the process that has the exception.

Here is your fixed code

```
import simpy

env = simpy.Environment()

def go():
    try:
        yield env.process(function_call())
    except Exception as e:
        # Exception handling code
        print('exception hadling in go')

def function_call():
    yield env.process(diff_process())

def diff_process():
    yield env.timeout(1)
    raise Exception

def helper():
    yield env.process(go())
    yield env.timeout(2)

def main():
    env.process(helper())
    env.run()
main()
print('done')
```